# Tree Array Parent Node Updation in PHP

Tags: php, recursion

I have an array like this:

```
Array(
[id] => test1
[data] => Array([balance] => 0 )
[has_children] => 1
[children] => Array(
        [0] => Array
            ([id] => test2
            [data] => Array([balance] => 45)
            [has_children] => 
            )
        [1] => Array(
                [id] => test3
                [data] => Array([balance] => 78)
                [has_children] => 
            )
        [2] => Array(
                [id] => test55
                [data] => Array([balance] => 0)
                [has_children] => 1
                [children] => Array(
                        [0] => Array(
                                [id] => test45
                                [data] => Array([balance] => 90)
                                [has_children] => 
                            )
                    )
            )
        [3] => Array(
                [id] => test567
                [data] => Array([balance] => 123)
                [has_children] => 
            )
        [4] => Array(
                [id] => test79
                [data] => Array([balance] => 34)
                [has_children] => 
            )
    )
)
```

I want to update parent balance as SUM(child node's balance). How to update this one. 
Parent Node balance as (SUM (child node's balance).

This is my Code:

```
foreach ($array as &$each) {
    $balance = 0;
    $this->getBalance($each,$balance);
    $array['data']['balance'] = $balance;
    print_r($array);
    exit;
}
public function getBalance($data, &$balance) {
    $balance += $data['data']['balance'];
    if (isset($data['has_children']) && $data['has_children']) {
        if (isset($data['children']) && !empty($data['children'])) {
            foreach ($data['children'] as &$eachChildren) {
                $this->getBalance($eachChildren, $balance);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

In this code parent node balance only added, updated. How to update all parent node balances???

Comment: 1.Please show us your code effort you tried so far to overcome your problem. 2. Add expected outcome to your question too

Comment: ya. i updated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct code:

```
public function assignBalances(&$balanceData)
    {
        foreach ($balanceData as &$each)
        {
            $balance = 0;
            $this->getBalance($each, $balance);
            $each['data']['balance'] = $balance;
            if ($each['has_children'])
            {
                $level++;
                $this->assignBalances($each['children']);
            }
        }

    }

    public function getBalance($data, &$balance)
    {
        $balance += (int) ($data['data']['balance']);
        if (isset($data['has_children']) && $data['has_children'])
        {
            if (isset($data['children']) && !empty($data['children']))
            {
                foreach ($data['children'] as &$eachChildren)
                {
                    $this->getBalance($eachChildren, $balance);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It's working perfect..

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array["children"] as $key=>$value){
  $sum = 0;
  if($value["has_children"] != ""){
  foreach($value["children"] as $k1=>$v1){
    $sum += (int)$v1["data"][0]["balance"];
  }
  $value["data"][0]["balance"] = $sum;
 }
}
```

Initialize `$sum` with value 0 in loop. Loop through the outer array and check for each key if it has_children? if yes the again loop through the inner array and add the balance to $sum variable. At the end of inner loop you will have total of balance of all children. Now assign this total to outer array's balance.

### Update

For infinite children

```
foreach($array["children"] as $key=>$value){
      if($value["has_children"] != ""){
      $value["data"][0]["balance"] = get_sum($value["children"]);
     }
    }

   function get_sum($child_array){
   $innersum = 0;
   foreach($child_array as $k=>$v){
     if($v["has_children"] == ""){
      $innersum += $v["data"][0]["balance"];
     }else{
      get_sum($v["children"]);
     }
   }
   return $innersum;
   }
```

Comment: Which array has infinite of children? @SARAN

Comment: It's an dynamic array. So couldn't guess no.of children nodes.

Comment: You are talking about main array $array? @SARAN

Comment: No.. The children nodes also has more no. of children arrays.

Comment: I have updated my if condition, Please try now. @SARAN

Comment: It's not working. Want to update each parent node balance as sum of it's children node balance. for example : array[0][sum] = array[0][1][sum] + (array[0][2][sum] = array[0][2][0][sum] + array[0][2][1][sum] ) + array[0][3][sum] + array[0][4][sum] + array[0][5][sum] @Smit

Comment: Check update. You will need a recursive function. I haven't checked it so please ignore syntax errors if any. Also It will update the value of top most parent node with the sum of its children node. @SARAN